# Python serial module works in command line but not from script

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

For reference I have used pyserial for dozens of hours succesfully

When I

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial()
>>> ser.baudrate = 115200
>>> ser.port = "/dev/ttyACM0"
>>> ser.open()
```

it works exactly as expected. however, when i call the exact same sequence in a python3 script and run it I get a "AttributeError: module 'serial' as no attribute 'Serial'.

When I run `dir()` on both serial modules I get the expected result from my command line serial, but I only get like 5 functions listed when I do print the results of `dir(serial)` in my script. After running my script which fails, the command line serial version no longer works either. I have to pip uninstall and reinstall it for it to work again.

For reference I am on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I've tested and verified that running `import serial; ser = serial.Serial()`
works when I do it both from the interpreter, and when I run it from a script, have you redefined your python command to alias to something else that might not be using the same interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

bad mistake! I had named the python script I was trying to run was called serial.py!!

that was conflicting with importing the serial library